# Get attribute from tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, tooltipster

I'm using `tooltipster` to generate tooltips, but I want to set the tooltip based on a data attribute from the element it's attached to. How do I get the associated data so I can set the image url as shown below. This is what I've been trying:

```
$(".test").tooltipster({
  var datainfo = $(this).data("info");
  content: $('<div class="desc"><img src="img/'+datainfo+'.jpg"/></div>')
});
```

My HTML is basically:

```
<div class="test tooltip" data-info="AAA">Testing</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameter is json, not a function block so you need to take your datainfo line out of there (it's javascript, not json). Maybe this will work for you:

```
var datainfo = $(".test").data("info");
$(".test").tooltipster({
  content: $('<div class="desc"><img src="img/'+datainfo+'.jpg"/></div>')
});
```

I suppose you are wanting to set a number of tooltips that show images in this case, let's assume that each one has the class "test".

```
$(".test").each(function(){
  $(this).tooltipster({
      content: $('<div class="desc"><img src="img/' + $(this).data("info") + '.jpg"/></div>')
  });
});
```

Comment: yes yes yes !!! thanks you !!! this is what I want ! thanks for your second solution !

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin may not work in this way. You are passing couple of lines of code instead of key, value pair of options in the plugin. 
If you want `data-info` value, simple solution will be to bind the mouseover event and then get that attribute value.

**Example:**

```
$(".test").on("mouseover",function(){
    var datainfo = $(this).attr("data-info");
});
```

**Note:** In case the plugin removes the data-attribute, then you might need to use another attribute for getting the src of image.

Comment: I have try your second solution but undefined value

Comment: What does `$(this)` refer to? (in your answer that uses tooltipster)

Comment: @jcuenod refer to the `.test` , but someone has already answer a nice solution

Comment: No it doesn't that's the problem with this solution. The scope is not  `$(".test")` (which is why you get undefined).

Comment: @jcuenod yeah, didn't noticed the plugin structure.

Comment: @KK `$(this)` still doesn't have the context you need it to have in your second solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well a small trick you can try here!!

Add a classname `tooltipShow` [or anything] on which you want to display tooltips. Use that class to capture `hover` on your element like below:

```
$('.tooltipShow').on('hover',function(){
    $(this).tooltipster({
         content: $('<div class="desc"><img src="img/'+$(this).data('info')+'.jpg"/></div>')
    });
});
```

Comment: Have a look at the plugin.